# Use default (built-in) asp.net user registration and login in deployed azure website with my own database

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, authentication, user-registration

Is it possible to use the default asp.net user registration in my deployed website in azure? 
Also I want to use my own database with it, not the default MSSQLLocalDB - Filename.mdf file.

Comment: Yes. It is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  The connection strings are overwritten by the Data Connections when you deploy your code.  Create a SQL Server (logical server) resource, then create a database.  Finally, go to App Service and use Data Connections to link the database to your App Service.  Most important - make sure the connection string name is the same as your app expects.  Once that has done (and potentially after a restart of the service), you should be up and running with the data stored in SQL Azure.